# Ignoring insert of first new line

Tags: php

I am trying to read txt file, find $id and increment it's value `$id=>value`. But the problem is that when I want to save changes the first new line is ignored so

```
10=>26
30=>11
33=>22
```

became this after I run the script

```
10=>2730=>11
33=>22
```

This

```
10=>26
30=>11
33=>22
```

Should result in this

```
10=>27
30=>11
33=>22
```

Here is the code. I am using `$id = 10`.

```
 $tmp= "";
    $file = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/requests.txt", "r");
    $file = explode("\n", $file);
    foreach ($file as $product){

        $data = explode("=>", $product);
        if($data[0] == $id) {
            $data[1] += 1;
            $product = $data[0]."=>".$data[1];
            $tmp = $tmp.$product."\n";
            continue 1;
        }
        $tmp = $tmp.$product."\n";
    }
    echo $tmp;
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/abc.txt", $tmp);
```

Comment: Try using `\r\n` or `PHP_EOL`?

Comment: `PHP_EOL` solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! `:)`